# Why am I getting so many error messages in phpmyadmin localhost?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

[image: The error messages I am getting]

I just set up XAMPP and, when I start the Apache localhost, it displays all of these errors when I search "localhost/phpmyadmin"

I am very new to this (just downloaded XAMPP) and I watched this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqfIksHKPPg on setting it up (I didn't install phpmyadmin since it was already installed with XAMPP)

I edited the notepad text files as stated in the video, but instead of a login, I get all of the error messages shown in the above picture...

I also opened config.inc.php and edited the line:

```
['Servers'][$i]['(MySQL root password)'] = '';$cfg
```

so it matched MySQL root password

Even if you have a suggestion to fix one of the errors, please still comment

Also, if you need any more information please let me know

Comment: Which version of MySQL

Comment: The line you edited !??? Looks like you naffed that line up. Are you using `notepad`

Comment: Does thi shappen after you try and enter (or ignore) the login screen?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I used the window's builtin notepad to edit that line.

No login screen appears on the localhost/phpmyadmin webpage.

I used notepad to edit the config.inc file for a different line, but I changed it to the same password

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['(MySQL's root password here)'] = '';

As for the version: 8.0.18

Comment: By the way, it's more helpful if you copy and paste the error text rather than an image of the error message. Not only does it make it easier for us to answer, but future people with the same problem cannot search for text from an image.

Comment: As RiggsFolly asks, it would be helpful to know not only your MySQL but also PHP versions.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting several error messages because you have several problems :)

> Cannot connect: invalid settings

Some setting is incorrect, most likely something in your `config.inc.php` is misspelled or incorrectly copied and pasted. Specifically, if the line `['Servers'][$i]['(MySQL root password)'] = '';$cfg` is actually how it appears in your configuration, that is clearly the problem as the line should actually be `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'green';` except with you password instead of 'green'...except that only applies if your auth_type is 'config', otherwise the 'password' line isn't used at all (since you're prompted for the password at log in). I'm not sure what XAMPP does here for auth_type, but I don't think you should have had to edit the configuration file at all, since you used the XAMPP installer which should have configured everything.

> The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [sha256_password]

This appears to be a bit of a version mismatch in your installed files. [Access denied after setting user's password with SHA256 in phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348223/access-denied-after-setting-users-password-with-sha256-in-phpmyadmin) goes in to more detail, but this most often occurs when you've got MySQL 8 and PHP older than 7.4. Normally, I'd suggest upgrading your PHP version — but you're using the packaged XAMPP, which certainly wouldn't ship with conflicting MySQL and PHP versions, so something is odd here. Please confirm for us your MySQL and PHP versions. You didn't happen to have an existing MySQL or PHP installation before you installed XAMPP, did you?

> Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed

This is probably related to the MySQL 8/PHP 7.4 conflict. There is an administrative user (called the controluser) that phpMyAdmin can use to manage some extra features, ordinarily you wouldn't need it to access phpMyAdmin (only to access those additional features), but it seems XAMPP has configured this for you. Since the authentication fails, you get an additional message that the controluser was not able to connect.

You could bypass this by commenting out the configuration lines referencing controluser and controlpass, although again the XAMPP package should have this all configured so I don't recommend that at this point.

The other messages are basically echoes of the previous messages; you get an additional protocol notification because the controluser is trying the same sha256 connection type that the main user was, and then finally phpMyAdmin is telling you that MySQL rejected the connection.

If this is a fresh XAMPP install, I'd suggest reinstalling, because something got a bit confused. I'd also suggest making sure that you don't have any other conflicting software running — XAMPP is a package of all the included parts, so you don't want to install or run your own Apache or MySQL instance which would interfere with the packaged kit.