# Phpmyadmin Login

Tags: phpmyadmin, lamp

Im running LAMP: on Ubuntu: 19.10.1, PHP:7.3.11, Apache:2.4.41, MySql: 8.0.18.

Im having a lot of issues logging into phpmyadmin with root user as well as another admin user.

Here's the error messages: 
1) 'mysqli_real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client'

2) '[mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the clientcaching_sha2_password]'

I've run 'sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin' several times and tried different 'authentication modes' and nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php mysqli\_connect: authentication method unknown to the client \[caching\_sha2\_password\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026939/php-mysqli-connect-authentication-method-unknown-to-the-client-caching-sha2-pa)

Comment: The answer appears to be a duplicate of the one I provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59381769/2385479

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access denied after setting user's password with SHA256 in phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348223/access-denied-after-setting-users-password-with-sha256-in-phpmyadmin)