# Mysql 8.0.18 y PhpMyadmin 4.4.x

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have installed the MySQL 8.0 server and phpMyAdmin, but when I try to access it from the browser the following "The MySQL server did not authorize your access"

background:
1. by command line if I log in and I can create databases and everything.
2. with another Navigate Premiun application if I can access.
Issue:
With PHPMYADMIN I get this message.
"The MySQL server did not authorize your access"

help me, please

Comment: You must use mysql native password. sha2_caching is not supported by PHP fully yet. Another option would be to upgrade to PHP 7.4 where this is supported, but it is not guaranteed to work 100%.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [phpMyAdmin on MySQL 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49948350/phpmyadmin-on-mysql-8-0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access denied after setting user's password with SHA256 in phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348223/access-denied-after-setting-users-password-with-sha256-in-phpmyadmin)