# Access Denied phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

[image]

please help when I open `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` can't get in there and got a lot of error and I new in PHP my admin
problem :

1. `mysqli::real_connect()`: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [sha256_password]
2. `mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2054)`: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
   Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
3. `mysqli::real_connect()`: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]
4. `mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2054)`: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
   phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should 5. check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Comment: I highly recommend using HeidiSQL.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin, PHP, and MySQL versions are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access denied after setting user's password with SHA256 in phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348223/access-denied-after-setting-users-password-with-sha256-in-phpmyadmin)