# cant login on phpmyadmin after installation

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have installed a new server with windows 2019 server.
Then im trying to install mysql and phpmyadmin.
I have manage to install php and that works.

I follow this tut to install mysql : https://www.bogdancaraman.com/blog/en/how-to-install-mysql-on-windows-server.html

And this one for phpmyadmin: https://www.bogdancaraman.com/blog/en/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-on-windows-server.html

I follow everything, and when i try to login on localhost/phpmyadmin i get errors.

- Unable to log in to MySQL server
- mysqli::real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [sha256_password]
- mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
- Connection for control users according to your configuration failed.
- mysqli::real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]
- mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

I have uninstall phpmyadmin and mysql and try again, but the error is still there.
Hope someone can help me.

Comment: It may be version mismatch, which version of PHP and what version of MySQL are compatible. It looks like it doesn't know the method "sha256_password". Also here are some semi-relevant tips? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026939/php-mysqli-connect-authentication-method-unknown-to-the-client-caching-sha2-pa Hope that helps. Otherwise someone may know the answer if you give the versions of PHP/MySQL :)

Comment: thanks it help me, it works now.

Comment: In addition to the related link posted by Rustyjim, this appears to be an exact duplicate of [Access denied after setting user's password with SHA256 in phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348223/access-denied-after-setting-users-password-with-sha256-in-phpmyadmin).

Comment: Perhaps this question belongs to a different site ? serverfault ?